# Toastr not showing up in laravel 5.4

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I tried to use Toast notification, I think I have included everything alright. It can be seen on page source that generated after the action, but it's not showing the notification on the page.

**The includes:**

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/toastr.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/toastr.min.js') }}"></script>
```

**The call:**

```
<script>
    @if(Session::has('success'))
        toastr.success("{{ Session::get('success') }}")
    @endif
</script>
```

**The controller:**

```
$this->validate($request, [
  'name' => 'required'
]);

$category = new Category; // create instance

$category->name = $request->name; //  take name from form request
$category->save(); // save it to database

Session::flash('success', 'Category Has Been Created :D');

return redirect()->route('categories');
```

and the following image shows that code has passed with success:

[image: code on page source]

Comment: is this CodeSeven/toastr library?!

Comment: Yes! is it from here: https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/

Comment: jQuery is required. Do you have jQuery imported in your page?

Comment: yes i have :  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Can you know the problem please!!

Comment: I'm sorry, i couldn't stimulate your situation (long set up). your code same to be Ok!
May be you should check the Dev console for any error that may stop your javascript execution.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem recently. To solve that, I made sure following:

(It's possibly point 4 in your case)

1) Link `toastr.css` and `toastr.js` in your layout file

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/toastr.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/toastr.min.js') }}"></script>
```

2) Do not use `defer` attribute in markup

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/toastr.min.js') }}" defer></script>
```

It should be:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/toastr.min.js') }}"></script>
```

3) Import [jQuery](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

4) Load jQuery before toastr

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/toastr.min.js') }}"></script>
```

5) Make sure the spellings, [functions](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr#quick-start), etc. are correct

Answer (score 0):

I simply made sure my scripts load at the bottom of my code just before the  tag, and that solved my problem.
`

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/toastr.min.js') }}" ></script>
<script>
    @if(Session::has('success'))

    toastr.success("{{ Session::get('success')}}")
    @endif

    @if(Session::has('info'))

    toastr.info("{{ Session::get('info')}}")
    @endif
</script>

</body>
</html>`
```

Initialy I had placed it inside the  tag